# How to solve problem with slash in selenium webdriver?

Tags: python, html, selenium

I have link-text in the form "Guntakal/ae/d1". I am not able to click on it.

```py
village=Guntakal/ae/d1
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text(village).click()
```

I must be able to click on it. Is there a problem with '/' or numbers in the name?  How to overcome this?

Comment: Inspect the link in DOM, it could be possible that the text separated by '/' (slash) are in different anchor tags. And are not part of a single link. If possible, share the relevant html code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It Should work whatever you have tried.However when you use `find_element_by_partial_link_text` you can use any partial text which is unique to the element.I guess in this case `d1` is the unique. Give it a try.

```
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("d1").click()
```

---

OR if you use variable try that.

```
village="Guntakal/ae/d1"
vilpartialText=village.split("/")[-1]
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text(vilpartialText).click()
```

Comment: Second solution worked in my case. Thanks KunduK. You saved my day :)

Comment: Great!!! Can you accept that answer by clicking hollow under down vote button so it will turn to green.Thanks.

Comment: Yeah! absolutely. And can you upvote my question so that I can post images in upcoming questions. I need 15 reputation to post a question with images unfortunately!

Comment: @G.S.J : Don't post any images on your post.This not gonna help OP to help you to resolve your query.Always provide html in text format.

Comment: I am working on Image processing also! So to post about certain critical images, I need this reputation thing to be atleast 15!